# Android: Multiple screen layout

Tags: android, size, screen, qualifiers

I am having problem creating layout for different devices. The old qualifier example small, normal and large, xlarge etc..

My layout is very simple. I just want the whole interface keep the same through different devices...

From the android website there is :

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

How should i define with new type of naming to replace small normal large etc..and does that mean i can't use small normal ... as the qualifier for new android os.

Comment: you can use these qualifiers layout for normal, layout-small for small and so on.

Comment: I thought they was deprecated after android 3.0 so i am a bit confused xLarge is for what screen?? is that a tablet size

Comment: If you want it to be the same, measure the the screen and resize layouts programmatically.

Comment: @Simon for xlarge use layout xlarge. Yes it supports tablet size.

Comment: In documentation, they suggest to use layout-sw600dp etc? what is wrong with layout-small etc. Sorry I am too confused with these stuff.

Comment: Yes you can create like this also it means devices with width atleast 600dp and above that use this layout.

Comment: Using sw600dp style is too specific to certain device .. I find it hard to make a decision of what is the smallest width i want for each layout. If i use small i understand it was for a small screen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For supporting different size screens you can create simply 4-layout folders. layout for normal size, layout-small for small, layout-large for large and layout-xlarge for xlarge screens. And for size of font you can create different values folder like `values, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi`. Then you can create values folder depending upon height or width and belongs to `ldpi` or `mdpi` i.e `values-w360dp-mdpi` or `values-h600dp-mdpi`. Then android automatically picks layout depending upon screen size and values on depending height or width. And you can combine these with new selectors. Like create `layout-sw600dp` for 7" tablets.

For [more information see this link.](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

Comment: @Simon mine pleasure.